# Which one of these 2 sentences is correct?

Tags: grammar

Can someone tell me which of these two sentences is correct?

> 1. I was going to ask you how **are** you?
> 2. I was going to ask you how **were** you?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you only use the subject/verb inversion and the question mark if you're asking a question in the moment.  Here you're actually making a statement about reported (hypothetical) speech - saying what you had planned to ask - so I'd use a period instead of a question mark and not use subject/verb inversion.  But in any case, either the present or past is acceptable depending on context:

> 1. I was going to ask you how you are.

This first version means that just a few moments ago, I was intending to ask you how you feel right now, but something stopped me.

> 2. I was going to ask you how you were.

This second version means that at some time in the past, I was intending to ask you how you felt at that past time.

Finally, if you do want to preserve the subject/verb inversion and the question mark, you can quote the question:

> 3. I was going to ask you, "How are you?"

This last version doesn't distinguish been the very recent past or the more distant past, since in either case the actual words you would have said are, "How are you?"

Answer (score -1):

"are you" is present tense, and means you want to know how that person is right now

"were you" is past tense, and means you want to know how that person was in the past.  In that case you'd say how were you when ____ happened.  It may also be used in the sense of how were you there (instead of somewhere else).

Answer (score -2):

Grammatically, both can be correct, it just depends on the context.

If you just was going to ask him about his mood **in the time of the question** (it doesn't matter if it's now or yesterday or month ago), then the correct sentence is

> "I was going to ask you how **are** you." = I was going to ask you "how **are** you now".

because "how are you" refers to the time of the question.

But if you was going to ask him **about his mood earlier** to the time of the question, then the second sentence is correct:

> I was going to ask you "how **were** you" = I was going to ask you "how are you some time ago" (a day / week / month / year before the time of the question).

Practically, I think that "how are you" is an idiom, and alternatives will work better in such case. For example: "I was going to ask you if everything is OK" or "I was going to ask you if everything was OK".